# How to get a Uri of the image stored in the resources

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, resources

I have two `.png` files added to my resources which I need to access their Uri when doing binding.

My `xaml` code is as followed:

```
<Grid>
  <Image>
    <Image.Source>
       <BitmapImage DecodePixelWidth="10" UriSource="{Binding Path=ImagePath}"/>
    </Image.Source>
  </Image> 
</Grid>
```

and the `binding` code using ***ImagePath*** is:

```
ImagePath = resultInBinary.StartsWith("1") ? Properties.Resources.LedGreen : Properties.Resources.ledRed;
```

However

```
Properties.Resources.LedGreen
```

returns a `Bitmap` instead of `String` containing the Uri of that particular image.
I just want to know how to extract that value without a need to address a path of the image in the directory that it's stored. (Which honestly I am not sure is a right thing to do as I couldn't find any similar situation on the net).

Please let me know if there is even a preferred method to the one I am trying to use if available.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

In a WPF application you would usually not store images in `Properties/Resources.resx` and access them by means of the `Properties.Resources` class.

Instead you just add the image files to your Visual Studio project as regular files, perhaps in a folder named "Images" or the like. Then you would set their `Build Action` to `Resource`, which is done in the Properties window. You get there e.g. by right-clicking the image file and select the `Properties` menu item. Note that the default value of the `Build Action` should be `Resource` for image files anyways.

In order to access these image resources from code you would then use a [Pack URI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069.aspx). With the above folder name "Images" and an image file named "LedGreen.png", creating such an URI would look like this:

```
var uri = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Images/LedGreen.png");
```

So you could perhaps declare your property to be of type Uri:

```
public Uri ImageUri { get; set; } // omitted INotifyPropertyChanged implementation
```

and set it like this:

```
ImageUri = resultInBinary.StartsWith("1")
         ? new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Images/LedGreen.png")
         : new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Images/LedRed.png");
```

Finally your XAML should look like shown below, which relies on built-in type conversion from Uri to ImageSource:

```
<Grid>
    <Image Width="10" Source="{Binding Path=ImageUri}" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thanks for the descriptive answer and more importantly a suggestion about the right way of doing this. I have implemented my solution in the way you suggested however I am wondering do I need to carry and keep these images with the executable that I am gonna hand in to the other team? Since this is a fairly simple project I am not planning to make an installer for it.

Comment: No, the `Resource` Build Action adds the image files to the assembly. So they are contained in the executable.

Answer (score 1):

Declare the `Properties.Resources.LedGreen` property as `ImageSource` and set it to Uri location rather than the Bitmap object.

Or if you insist of storing it as a bitmap you can get the source by returning `Properties.Resources.LedGreen.ImageSource` which will be of type `ImageSource`.

I would prefer the first approach.