# Handling of pictures in WPF projects

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm new to WPF and is trying to learn as much as I can about it. Before I used winforms and back then I added pictures to the projects by using the resource-system. To call for pictures I then used:

```
Properties.Resouces.<Name of resource>
```

Now, in WPF I thought I would use something similiar and add pictures to the projects resources (just to make sure they are distributed with the application), but I'm a bit unsure of how to call them. For example, I'm trying to change the background of the form by the following XAML:

```
<Window.Background>
        <ImageBrush>
            <ImageBrush.ImageSource>
                <BitmapImage UriSource="Resources\background.png"/>
            </ImageBrush.ImageSource>
        </ImageBrush>
    </Window.Background>
```

This is obviously not working. If I had the full path to the file in URIsource it works, but I dont want to force endusers to use a specific folder for usage.

In this case background.png is added as a resource to the project with the setting "Copy to output directory" set to "Copy if newer". I therefore know that the picture will be in the root of the project (under Resources-folder ofc) but I dont know how to relate to the root folder flexible enough. Which brings me to my questions:

1. How do I refer to the path of the project? In xaml and c#
2. Is this a proper way of handling this or am I way out of line?

I think I've attached all necessary info and I'm sorry if I didnt. Im new to WPF but I'm trying to learn. If you are about to downgrade this question, please leave a comment on why.

Thanks in advance, 
Dave

Comment: by default relative source does work. ImageBrush also have a property ImageSource, that can also be used if feasible.

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22957974/1136211) for how it is done in WPF.

Comment: Have a look at the pack uri - I have used this but can't find an example at the moment... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is far more common to add your images into a folder, let's say named `Images` in the root folder of your project. You should use Visual Studio's *Add Existing Item* command for this, as it will correctly set the *Build Action* and *Copy to Output Directory* properties for you. Once you have added your image files, you can reference them simply with `string` file paths like this:

```
<Image Source="pack://application:,,,/AppName;component/Images/ImageName.png" />
```

You can find out more about the file path syntax to use from the [Pack URIs in WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069(v=vs.110).aspx) page on MSDN.