# Icons and Images as Resource

Tags: wpf

I'm developing an app with C# and WPF, I've too many mini png images (icons).
All of the images' **Build Action** proerty is set to **Resource**. I can reach them with `ProjectName.Properties.Resources.SAMPLEICON` **on code behind.** But I need to reach them with XAML code. Can you help me with doing that?

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22957974/1136211).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get a Uri of the image stored in the resources](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22955317/how-to-get-a-uri-of-the-image-stored-in-the-resources)

Answer (score 1):

You must declare your xmlns in this way:

```
xmlns:properties="clr-namespace:YourProjectName.Properties.Resources"
```

Now it's time to define your Image:

```
<Image x:Name="imgName" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="12" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="14" Margin="157,36,0,0" Cursor="Hand" MouseUp="ShowProperties_MouseUp" Source="{Binding Source={x:Static properties:Resources.SAMPLEICON}}"/>
```

Hope it helps.