# Show the image by string in WPF C# apps

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have images as Resources in Resources Folder

I want to show image by string value in ImageController

Here is the code What I am going to use.

```
<UserControl x:Class="WinIPTVApp.Pages.Content.Views.MenuItemUserControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WinIPTVApp.Pages.Content.Views"
         mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Grid>
        <Image Source="" x:Name="Icon"/>
        <ListBoxItem x:Name="ListViewItemMenu" Content="{Binding Path=Header}" Padding="37 14" FontSize="15"
                 Foreground="White" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

This is the codes for xaml.cs.

```
Image Icon;
string user_icon = "user.png";
Icon = new Bitmap(new Uri(user_icon));
```

Please help me how to solve this problem.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: _"Not working"_ is not a useful problem statement. Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66558111/edit) so that it includes a proper [mcve], along with a detailed explanation of what the code does now, how that's different from what you want, and what _specifically_ you need help with. Be sure you include the _verbatim_ text of any error messages that are produced. Don't forget to check the debugger output for error messages there, such as exceptions and binding errors.

Comment: A few things are obviously wrong. You must not reassign the Icon field. You should not use the WinForms Image or Bitmap classes. You must use the value of the icon variable, not the string literal "icon". Assuming that icon holds a valid image URL or image file path, this should work: `Image.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(icon));`

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22957974/1136211. Assuming there is a file user.png in a project folder named Resources, the Build Action of the file should be set to `Resource`. It would be loaded by a Resource File Pack URI like `Image.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Resources/user.png"));`

Comment: Or with the user_icon variable: `Image.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri($"pack://application:,,,/Resources/{user_icon}"));`

Comment: Thank you for your kindness help, @Clemens

Answer (score 0):

I just found answer and this is working well.

```
Icon.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri($"pack://application:,,,/Resources/{user_icon}"));
```