# Button with transparent png image in .Net WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, image, button, transparency

I have a WPF Button which should be displayed with a png image which has transparent areas.

This is my xaml code, which works for displaying an image:

```
<Button HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Panel.ZIndex="2" Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="Transparent">
    <Image Width="1cm" Height="1cm" x:Name="LogoImageChangeButton_Image"/>
</Button>
```

This is the image. As you can see, it has transparent areas:
[image]

Unfortunately, wpf seems to repeat or assume pixels in the transparent areas for some unknown reason. Unfortunately, the effect looks quite glitchy so I cant describe it any better:
[image]

I have tried around with different stretch modes, all seemed to have this issue. Any help is appreciated.

This is how I set the image:

```
LogoImageChangeButton_Image.Source = BitmapHelper_Net.BitmapConverter.Convert(Properties.Resources.ChangeImageIcon);
```

and this is how I convert the bitmap to an imagesource:

```
public static BitmapImage Convert(Bitmap src)
{
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    ((System.Drawing.Bitmap)src).Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
    BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
    image.BeginInit();
    ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    image.StreamSource = ms;
    image.EndInit();
    return image;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use BMP as conversion format. It does not support transparency.

Use PNG, and set `BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad` to be able to dispose of the stream after `EndInit`.

```
public static BitmapImage Convert(Bitmap src)
{
    var image = new BitmapImage();

    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        src.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
        ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

        image.BeginInit();
        image.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
        image.StreamSource = ms;
        image.EndInit();
    }

    return image;
}
```

Comment: thank you so much. I thought that .bmp is a bitmap, which supports alpha channel in .Net

Comment: As the other formats, BMP is an encoding format, e.g. for image files. But why do you have a `Bitmap` at all, instead of directly creating a BitmapImage from the source file?

Comment: A much better solution is not to do this in the first place, `Image` can load directly from the resource stream, you don't need to do this weird encoding and decoding.

Comment: I am deploying a single-file solution. I could not find a way to load the image directly from resources.resx or how to supply the image in a single file app otherwise. If you know a better solution, I'd be happy for an answer.

Comment: You do not load an image from resources.resx in WPF. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22957974/1136211

Comment: @Blindy Image can not do that directly. The conversion from string, Uri, Stream, or byte array is performed by an instance of ImageSourceConverter, the TypeConverter registered for the ImageSource type.

Comment: Worked well that tutorial. Thank you for the explanations.